# difference between factory methods and constructors

Tags: objective-c, swift, constructor, initializer, factory-method

learning Objective and Swift at the moment. I understand initialisers in Obj C and convenience initialisers and I understand Factory methods. I have also heard the term "constructors" but I am not sure how they differ from factory methods or initialisers. Is "constructor" just another way to refer to initialisers? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference.

For a long time class methods that create instance objects had been called convenience allocators or – rarely – constructors. The term convenience allocators often has been used, when an instance object was autoreleased, what became unimportant with ARC.

```
NSString *string1 = [NSString string]; // autoreleased
NSString *string2 = [NSSString new];   // ownership transfer
```

Basically they are a combination of `+alloc` and `-init…` plus – when it is a convenience allocator – `-autorelease`. Two (?) years ago or so the started to call them factor methods.

However, forget about names. Think about what they do and why they exist: With a classical `+alloc`-`-init…` combination the class had no chance to decide, what subtype to create, because that depends on the arguments of `-init`. Let's have an example: `NSSArray` has two (private) subclasses `_NSSmallArray` and `_NSBigArray`. It wants to chose the subtype from the estimated size you give as capacity on an `-initWithEstimatedSize:` method. How can `+alloc` decide, which subtype to chose and allocate? It has no idea, what argument you will pass on the init method.

With constructors or convenience allocators, object allocation can be parametrized. `+newArrayWithEstimatedSize:` or `+arrayWithEstimatedSize:` can solve that problem.

Eh, now you have to call them factory methods. Sorry. The story is the same.

Comment: This is tagged [swift], not really clear if OP was actually looking for Swift info, but maybe worth noting that Swift did [formalize the term "convenience _initializer_"](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-ID216), and "initializers" in Swift cover the functionality for which "constructors" are used in ObjC.

Comment: It is tagged with Swift and Objective-C. Since the concept in Swift is lent from Objective-C, you can describe it with Objective-C. The rest is wording as mentioned in the last three paragraphs.